# Uploading to S3 - new "unsafe script" AKA "ran insecure content" error in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, file-upload, amazon-s3

On my Rails app, I'm letting users directly upload files to S3. I'm doing this through an iframe, and the upload takes place with Javascript.

Quite recently (e.g. within the last month), something changed within Chrome's (and Firefox's) security settings, such that it no longer runs this script automatically. Instead, some portion of my upload script is *blocked* by default. This means that the upload fails unless you click the shield (see attachment) that appears on the right side of the URL bar and explicitly allow the script to run.

[image: Shield]

Does anyone know how I can get around this, so that my users don't have to click on this shield every time (e.g. is there a way I ? Or does anyone know how I can begin to identify which script is "unauthenticated," so I can avoid having this issue appear to begin with?

FYI, an error pops up in my developer console at the same time the shield appears:

```
[blocked] The page at https://www.my_domain.com/seekers/new ran insecure content from http://s3.my_domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com/.
```

Does this mean that the insecure content is coming from http://s3.[my_domain].com.s3.amazonaws.com/?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that the insecure content is coming from http://s3.[my_domain].com.s3.amazonaws.com/?

Yes.

> Does anyone know how I can get around this, so that my users don't have to click on this shield every time (e.g. is there a way I ?

There is no way other than serving all [active content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent) from an https domain. Allowing such content is a real security vulnerability anyway: It would allow a Man-In-The-Middle attacker to replace the unencrypted data stream in flight, allowing him to execute arbitrary code in the context of the secure site (to steal user data, user sessions or mess with user data).

> Or does anyone know how I can begin to identify which script is "unauthenticated," so I can avoid having this issue appear to begin with?

Firefox will show you the full URL and even rough location where the load was initiated (incl. line number if initiated from another script). E.g. Script tag:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://example.org/test.js" @ https://example.org/testblock.html
```

Injected script from another script (note the line number):

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://example.org/test2.js" @ https://example.org/testblock.html:7
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://pages.github.com/. You can link a project page to a repository containing your .js files, then use the .io path to the file to source them in your app using https://